# Stacking two different weapon buffs

Tags: dnd-5e, psionics, unearthed-arcana

With the 5th Edition Unearthed Arcana Mystic Class one of the classes has the Hone the Blade ability to give its weapon a +4 to attack and damage rolls and it remains non-magical. Also with the Psionics Weapon (Augmented Weapon) discplines you can make a weapon you're holding magical with a +3 to attack and damage rolls.

My main DM is saying they cannot stack on top one another because a rule I'm not seeing in PHB, but I'm not able to look into any of the other books to try to find this information. Can I get some help with this?

Comment: Could you add the names of the ability and discipline you're referring to?

Comment: "Home the Blade" ability from the Soul Knife subclass and the "Psionic Weapon" discipline using the Augmented Weapon ability from it.

Comment: @Mark Cogan, it does say. Hone the Blade & Pisionic Weapon, Augmented Weapon.

Answer (score 9):

### They should stack.

Assuming you are using [version 3](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf) of the Mystic Class the +3 ability is Psionic Weapon:Augmented Weapon, and the +4 is Hone the Blade class feature of Order of the Soul Knife, I see nothing immediately that would preclude you from stacking these bonuses. It would cost you 12 points, and the former is a 7 pt ability, meaning you would not be able to use it until 9th level.

Your DM may be thinking of the rule about figuring things like Armor Class, where you can only have one formula, and you can choose the more favorable one. In general, in 5th Edition, Formulas may be used once, but bonuses do indeed, stack.

Comment: 12 Points, not 13. Just a little correction.

Comment: They should stack, but keep in mind, that "Augmented Weapon" requires concentration. So, when the DM decides that the enemies focus on the guy who cuts through everything, you might loose it quickly.

Comment: @Twiggy Fixed. Don't tell my wife, the math teacher.

Comment: I think the more likely comparison isn't AC, but the fact that multiple bonuses can't stack if they're from the same-named effect. I.e. one can't benefit twice from being the target of two *bless* spells, even when cast by two people. (And your answer would still be correct if the GM were thinking of this, because the sources of bonuses to the weapon aren't same-named.)

Comment: True, but since the main question is answered, I'm not sure if an edit is warranted.